# On Schwarz Zippel Lemma

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Theorem (Schwartz, Zippel). Let $P\in F[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ be a non-zero polynomial of total degree $d≥0$ over a Field $F$. Let $S$ be a finite subset of $F$ and let $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$ be selected at random independently and uniformly from $S$. Then $Pr[P(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)=0]\leq\frac{d}{|S|}$.

It seems to work for $f=\frac{P}{Q}\in F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Why isn't the lemma quoted for rational functions?

Answer (score 3):

If $Q$ is always non-zero then $P = 0$ iff $P/Q = 0$, so there is no need to phrase a new lemma. If $Q$ can be zero then you need to explain how you interpret $P/Q$ at values at which $Q = 0$. We can say that the probability the fraction of zeroes and poles of $P/Q$ is at most $(\deg P + \deg Q)/|S|$.

Comment: So $Pr[f=0] = Pr[P=0 \mbox{ and }Q\neq 0] = Pr[P=0]Pr[Q\neq 0]\leq\frac{deg(P)}{|S|}Pr[Q\neq 0]\leq\frac{deg(P)}{|S|}$ does not work?

Comment: Definitely not, $P$ and $Q$ are not independent. Consider for example the case $P=Q=x_1$. Then $\Pr[P=0\text{ and }Q\neq 0] = 0$ but $\Pr[P=0],\Pr[Q\neq 0]$ are non-zero.

Comment: You can use $\Pr[P=0\text{ and }Q\neq 0] \leq \Pr[P=0] \leq \deg P/|S|$.

Comment: but why is this never quoted in references but only used in context of polynomials?

Comment: Since it's an elementary fact, and rational functions are not too common in the area. There are other generalizations you could come up with, say analyzing $P\cdot f$ where $f$ is a complicated function whose range is $\pm 1$.

Comment: In $P\cdot f$, I assume $P$ is polynomial, $f$ is rational function and $\cdot$ is multiplication. $f$ is rational implies you have zeros and hence its range cannot be $\pm1$.

Comment: No, $f$ is an arbitrary function that happens never to vanish.

Comment: like $a^{s(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$ where $s$ is real polynomial and $a\in\{-1,1\}$? This is the only thing I can think of? How is this applicable or useful? $s$ cannot be rational for range reasons.

Comment: It can be completely arbitrary. Arbitrary functions do show up. It is true that over a finite field, every function can be represented as a polynomial, but in general this polynomial will have high degree.

Comment: That is true. You are correct. I think this is an interesting point. Thank you.